# Cocos2d collision works but cannot be detected by b2contactListener

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, collision-detection, box2d-iphone

i've got a problem about b2contactListener.

i have these two classes:

```
class Terrain
class Hero
```

Each class got a method called:
`getHeroBody` -> returns the `b2body` of the hero.
`getTerrainBody` -> returns the `b2body` of the Terrain.

Each class got a method called `(id)initWithWorld:(b2World *)world;` that takes a `b2World`

When i create 2 objects on these classes i use the same `b2World`.

Now the problem is:
Collisions work but all the method to detect these collisions return always a null array, 0, in other words no collisions.

here is the declaration

```
MyContactListener *_contactListener;

_contactListener = new MyContactListener();
_world->SetContactListener(_contactListener);
```

here is 2 cycles the game never enters:

//FIRST WAY NOT WORKING

```
std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin();pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) { //never enters
    MyContact contact = *pos;
    for(b2Fixture *terrain_fixture = [_terrain getTerrainBody]->GetFixtureList(); terrain_fixture; terrain_fixture = terrain_fixture->GetNext()){
        for (b2Fixture *char_fixture = [_hero getHeroBody]->GetFixtureList(); char_fixture; char_fixture = char_fixture->GetNext()){
            if ((contact.fixtureA == terrain_fixture && contact.fixtureB == char_fixture) ||
                (contact.fixtureA == char_fixture && contact.fixtureB == terrain_fixture)) {
                isontheground = YES;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//SECOND WAY NOT WORKING

```
for (b2Contact* contact = _world->GetContactList(); contact; contact = contact->GetNext()){ //never enters
    isontheground = YES;
}
```

FIRST WAY USE THIS CLASS

```
MyContactListener::MyContactListener() : _contacts() {
```

}

MyContactListener::~MyContactListener() {
}

```
void MyContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) {
    // We need to copy out the data because the b2Contact passed in
    // is reused.
    MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB() };
    _contacts.push_back(myContact);
}

void MyContactListener::EndContact(b2Contact* contact) {
    MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB() };
    std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
    pos = std::find(_contacts.begin(), _contacts.end(), myContact);
    if (pos != _contacts.end()) {
        _contacts.erase(pos);
    }
}

void MyContactListener::PreSolve(b2Contact* contact,
                                 const b2Manifold* oldManifold) {
}

void MyContactListener::PostSolve(b2Contact* contact,
                                  const b2ContactImpulse* impulse) {
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by collision works ? Can you post the relevant collision and initialization code ?

Comment: in few words i never enter in this 
std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin();pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos)

Comment: what is _contacts in your contacts listener and how do you fill it ?

Comment: _contact is declared in mycollision class copied on the tutorial by Ray Wenderlich. The second "for" is a snippet found on the web and btw it never goes inside these two cycles

Comment: i edited the post with the class where _contat is.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

_world->Step() must be before the conctact listener in update function.
Sorry for the stupid question.